# ethereum wallet slowing down entire system (ubuntu 14)

Tags: synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I installed the wallet (0.8.7) on my Mac. Synced within 20 minutes, all good.
Trying to do the same on my Ubuntu 14 (on an lenovo x220, with ssd), and

1. it takes ages to sync (not the issue I am raising.. I am aware this problem has been discussed before) (rate is of a couple of blocks per minutes)
2. **the whole system becomes irresponsive when I run the wallet**. I.e., I can't browse or open a directory without having to wait 25 seconds etc.

I don't have to face slow downs on my machine when the Ethereum Wallet is not running. So what could be happening and how can I fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wallets/eth nodes generally use high disk I/O which heavily slows down systems that have an HDD or a slow SSD. If your system is an old, "low power" notebook it'll likely destroy your system performance overall, as the wallet takes up the majority of the I/O resources when sync'ing.

When it finishes sync'ing and catches up the blockchain head the load should drop and the system should be more responsive.

Comment: thanks. Any rough idea of minimum specs for reasonable execution then?

Comment: @harmut the thing that improves performance the most is keeping the chaindata on a separate disk (not just a separate partition, but an entirely separate disk) than the disk that your OS is on. If you do that, the node I/O won't trash the disk OS's cache and won't use up all the I/O resources on the OS disk. A good way to do this is to store your chaindata on a large, high-speed SD card or USB flash drive.

Comment: I have the latest version of the wallet(0.8.8) running on ubunto in a Dell xps13. 

This laptop is worth 2000$ and this wallet is totally slowing down everything. I keep killing the process all the time.